# System Log Dump on Tizen OS

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app

I am working for a project on Samsung Gear Fit2 which has Samsung's Tizen OS. I want to get system log dump to debug my application. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Settings > Gear info > About device> touch Software version menu 5times > Dial *#9900# > Run LOG_DUMP

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Settings>Gear Info>About Device
2. Scroll down to **Serial Number** and tap on it five times
3. (The number pad appears), enter *#9900#
4. Select **Run LOG_DUMP**
5. Connect to the Gear Fit2 via Tizen Studio
6. In Tizen Studio file explorer, select the log_dump file in /opt/usr/media/SLP_Debug/ and “pull” the file